# Turn on phone without Power and volume buttons

Tags: boot, power-on

I own Panasonic Eluga Ray Max phone, How can I turn it on without power and volume button as both are broken.
Device is already USB debugging enabled but adb cant see it while only charging.
So my basic requirement is to boot the phone.

Now another question is when I connect phone to PC/wall charger, screen lights up, charging status is show and general "power by android" message stay on screen for few seconds. So my question is there must be some sort of kernel gets loads just to display those messages and charging status, so why adb cant see device. and is there any other tool available which can boot a boot with command line when phone is displaying those message or charging status.

Comment: some flash tools work without power (+ they have auto reboot option) JIG dongle is available for old samsung devices (to enter download mode) https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221365

Answer (score 1):

> is there any other tool available which can boot a boot with command line when phone is displaying those message or charging status.

Nope. Not possible through software. A hardware hack is your only solution. Try to open the device and see if you can replace the button somehow.