# Turning on with ADB and SDK tools?

Tags: samsung

My samsung mobile is switched off with busted power button, and the "Volume down+main button with charger" process is also not working..is there a way I can restart it using adb and sdk tools??

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131248

Answer (score 0):

download magisk manager and exact variant of boot.img to any other android device. patch boot.img with advanced - keep force encryption + keep avb/dm-verity

install Odin and drivers. flash magisk_patched.tar in AP slot. set the auto reboot option

unlock device and install magisk manager. you are rooted

**edit:** now modify your device for auto boot each time charger is plugged in, see Irfan Latif's answer on [Automatically power on Android when the charger is connected](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221384)

<strike>now dump your para partition and inspect with hex editor. if you find the off mode charge string you can modify value. flash the modified para partition. this will make your device auto boot each time charger is plugged in</strike>

<strike>if the changes aren't persistent for some reason, install some start-up script which executes the mod directly</strike>

> `sed -i '0,/off-mode-charge=1/s/off-mode-charge=1/off-mode-charge=0/' $(find /dev/block -name by-name)/para`

Comment: This trick should work only on devices where bootloader supports `fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0`. I don't know if `odin` provides an equivalent command or not. But many vendors don't implement this command in bootloader.

Comment: Universal way: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221384/218526