# Samsung Tab A6 won't leave battery screen or turn on

Tags: samsung, battery, charging, boot, samsung-galaxy-tab

I'm currently having issues turn my A6 on, in that it simply won't start up.
I have tried: Holding the Power and Volume Down button, Holding the Power button for 30 secs, changing cables, changing adapters, changing wall sockets, and trying all manner of button combinations. Unfortunately the issue still persists.
When I plug the A6 in, the battery charging screen is displayed but doesn't change or do anything. If I unplug it, the battery charging screen stays for about 5 seconds and the switches off, leaving me with a dead tablet again.

Is this something I can fix, or do I need to get a replacement?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221365