# phone is on recovery mode , usb debugging is disable and power button is not working ? how to on or format the phone (samsung j7 2016)

Tags: recovery-mode, usb-debugging, buttons, power-on, formatting

i have samsung j7 2016 when i take out the battery and put it back it on without pressing power button and directly takes me to the recovery and I cant select anything because my power button not working plus my USB debugging is disabled

Comment: buy JIG dongle to awake device in download mode (or hold the proper key combo while inserting battery) https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221365